# $U \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{R}[t]_{<n} \stackrel{\lambda}{\to} \mathbb{R} $ is a continuous function, then $f$ is continuous too.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a function $U \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{R}[t]_{<n}$ , where $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}[t]_{<n}$ is the vector space of polynomiams with degree less than $n$ equipped with the natural vector space topology.

Is the following statement true?

> If forall evaluations $\lambda: \mathbb{R}[t]_{<n} \to \mathbb{R} $ sending a polynomial to its evaluation in $\lambda$, $p \mapsto p(\lambda$), the composition $$U \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{R}[t]_{<n} \stackrel{\lambda}{\to} \mathbb{R} $$ is a continuous function, then $f$ is continuous too.

---

**Motivation** for the question is the following:

$$ M(\mathbb{R}, n) \stackrel{p_t(\cdot)}{\to} \mathbb{R}[t]_{<n+1}, $$ i.e. the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is a continous function between these two spaces, and one can prove it by observing that each coefficient is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, but this trick is another proof of it.

Comment: This will hold true if $\lambda$ is a topological homeomorphism between the space of polynomials $\mathbb{R}[t]_{<n}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ because then the topology on the former can be identified by the family $\{\lambda^{-1}((a,b)); a<b\}$ (which is a basis). This is not true, but still this doesn't (dis)prove what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial of degree less than $n$ is determined by its values at $n$ points therefore by listing $n$ different $\lambda$s as a vector-valued $\Lambda$ you can make sure that the second map $\Lambda$ is a homeomorphism. Then $f$ can be viewed as the composition of $f\circ \Lambda$ with $\Lambda^{-1}$ so $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Take $ n $ distinct points $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n $. The function $ p\mapsto|(p (\lambda_1),\dots, p(\lambda_n))|$ is a norm on your vector space of polynomials with degree $<n$. Here $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your hypothesis says that $ f $ is continuous with respect to the topology induced by this norm (on the target).

But another norm is the maximum modulus of the coefficients of the polynomial, which induces your natural topology. The thesis now follows from the fact that any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space induce the same topology.

Comment: Of course the fact that the first norm vanishes only at the zero polynomial uses the identity principle for polynomials.